# Does calling firebase.auth count as a download for firebase's limits?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I've been trying to figure out through the documentation of firebase, what counts as a download and upload, since uploads are presumably free. I wanted to know if accessing authentication information is considered a download such as:

```
uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
```

Comment: you talking about uploading files to firestorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're showing is only using Firebase Authentication.  None of the Firebase Authentication APIs cost money, except for phone authentication after the free monthly quota has been exhausted.  Other Firebase products might have costs associated, as detailed in the [pricing guide](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

Comment: "None of the Firebase Authentication APIs cost money." Phone auth is a paid operation after the free quota. I know that doesn't apply here, but I'd still recommend clarifying.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. The number of authentications (signups and logins) don't count in the downloads. A very simple logic is that these are two different services of Firebase (Authentication and Database, just like storage and many others). Download just counts when you do a database transaction (get/post/put/delete). Hope this clears your confusion.